# set HTPasswd for specific GET request in a url

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd, cs-cart

I have a website build in cs cart.
 The url of administrator panel is like this `https://mysite.com/vendorsds.php`. 
 I want to set a **HTPasswd** for user whenever he/she visit this link `https://mysite.com/vendorsds.php?dispatch=companies.update`. 

I have tried the following -

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /var/chroot/home/content/28/11136228/html/htpasswds/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files vendorsds.php?dispatch=companies.update>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

When I remove `dispatch=companies.update` from above its working for all of the pages going through the **vendorsds.php**. 
Is it possible to set **HTPasswd** for any specific GET parameter (like `dispatch=companies.update`) in same page?

Answer (score 0):

This is really tricky but possible. See this 2 steps method below:

```
## force BASIC auth for a specific query parameter

# 1: set URI to /vendorsds.php/companies.update if query string is dispatch=companies.update
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)dispatch=companies.update(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(vendorsds\.php)/?$ $1/%1 [NC]

# 2: set AUTH_NEEDED var to 1 if URI is /vendorsds.php/companies.update
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/vendorsds\.php/companies\.update" AUTH_NEEDED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /var/chroot/home/content/28/11136228/html/htpasswds/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=AUTH_NEEDED
Satisfy any
```